# C# Bing Maps - response in XML, how to get adminDistrict2

Tags: xml, json, bing-maps

I have to pare the request from bing maps to get exact location. I'm living in Poland and what Im looking for is for example "Kęty (city), Oświęcimski (district), Małopolska (province)". Is it possible to get province and district from XML Bing Maps response, or I have to use JSON response? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

XML and JSON responses both CAN contain this data.  In JSON it is adminDistrict2, in XML is it AdminDistrict2.  It is contained within the Address (address in JSON) element.

An Address "CAN" contain an AdminDistrict2 but it does not appear to be required:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701725.aspx states:

> The postal address for the location. An address can contain
>   AddressLine, Neighborhood, Locality, AdminDistrict, AdminDistrict2,
>   CountryRegion, CountryRegionIso2, PostalCode, FormattedAddress, and
>   Landmark fields.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701726.aspx states:

> adminDistrict2: A string specifying the subdivision name in the country or region for
>   an address. This element is used when there is another level of
>   subdivision information for a location, such as the county.

Comment: Is there any possible to make query just with city name and country name,  and without other informations and get response to make promts in app?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your comment, but you should be able to do that by sending a request to "Find a Location by Query" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx and possibly also by using "Find a Location by Address" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx, Notice the "district" parameters are optional.

Comment: Sorry for my english. I am still not able to find location which is interesting for me. Results which I get doesnt contain it. Look at this:
http://www.bing.com/maps/#Y3A9NTAuMTE5NDAwfjE4Ljk4NDQwMCZsdmw9NiZzdHk9ciZ3aGVyZTE9a29uc3RhbnR5biVDMyVCM3c=

When you click "it's not it?" on the left you can choose locations with different district or provinces. That's what I need to do, but any query Im trying to use gives me error or wrong locations.

I hope it's clear now. And once again, sorry for english, didn't speak english for past 3 years ;)